# Best way to find bottlenecks on YII?

Tags: yii

I've tried the Debug Toolbar, but it doesn't quite cover my scenario. I simply want to know which pieces of code is taking the longest to execute. Is there a way to get a breakdown (perhaps a waterfall graph?) that can show me which methods took the longest to execute?

UPDATE: I was able to add various logging in the application, but unfortunately the part I thought was causing the slowness was in fact not causing the slowness. So, what is the easiest way I can add logging "across the board" in order to pinpoint any code that might be causing slowness?

Comment: To add to what schmunk said, `Yii::beginProfile/Yii::endProfile` might help.

Comment: FYI: I found out it was the less compiling that was killing the speed. However, I still would like to know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org) - a debugger and profiler tool for PHP.

You can generate profiling output and visualize it with 3rd party tools, [click here](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler) for details.